# If I cover my awrah while playing soccer(football), can i play regardless of whether the other players are playing without covering theirs?

Tags: awrah

Salam,
So I like to play soccer twice a week with the group of people I am able to find. I live in a country where Muslims are minority. So pretty much my whole group for playing is full of non-Muslims. They are good people and never do or say anything that can negatively impact my imman. I am the organizer of the group, i take care of scheduling the games and I play with them too. I do not schedule any games that will conflict with my prayer times or fasting. There is no gambling or money prizes. This is strictly for fun only. We rent the field, so the guys just pay me the money for field rental and a small admin fee for the organization/management of all this. Also this is mens game only, Women do not play with us.

My question is, I cover my awrah(navel to end of knee). But these non-Muslim guys will wear typical shorts that do not. Given I am covering my awrah during the game, can I still continue playing, given this game does not involve other haraam thing as mentioned abobe?

Thank you for your kind advice.